# AttributeError: <class 'aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2._IApplicationLoadBalancerProxy'>' object has no attribute 'metric_http_code_elb'

Tags: python, aws-cdk

I am using aws-cdk in Python & trying to reference an existing Load balancer and then make a call to Load balancer's 'metric_http_code_elb' attribute but getting below error:

```
AttributeError: '<class 'aws_cdk.Resource'>+<class 'aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2._IApplicationLoadBalancerProxy'>' object has no attribute 'metric_http_code_elb'.
```

Code snippet-

```
    load_balancer = elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer.from_lookup(
        self,
        "ALB",
        load_balancer_arn="arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:ap-south-1:345396902820:loadbalancer/app/QA-Env-Public-ALB/573f88222ed64875"
    )        
    http_5xx_metric = load_balancer.metric_http_code_elb()
```

Complete Code-
https://github.com/shiqs90/cdk-hands-on-project/blob/master/cw-dashboard/cw_dashboard/cw_dashboard_stack.py

Comment: This is the expected behaviour.  Existing resources "imported" with `fromSomethingName` and related methods return read-only, limited-functionality `ISomething` [interface types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/work-with.html#work-with-library-interfaces).

Comment: @fedonev:
What can we do to get ApplicationLoadBalancer object type in return rather than IApplicationLoadBalancer?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't supported by the CDK currently. Here is an open issue related to it: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10850

[This comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10850#issuecomment-712150191) explains it best:

> This isn't a bug. `FromTargetGroupAttributes` does not return a `ApplicationTargetGroup`, which is why you can't cast it to one. It does return a `IApplicationTargetGroupProxy`, which is a concrete implementation of a `IApplicationTargetGroup`.

> `IApplicationTargetGroup` doesn't currently support the metric* methods, as the metrics need the load balancer name, which an imported group doesn't have (at the moment).

As an alternative you could create a [Metric object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudwatch.Metric.html) by adding the dimensions, namespace, etc, yourself but it is a pain.